# javascript inheritance and instanceof operator discrepancy

Tags: javascript, instanceof, prototypal-inheritance

Consider the Constructor functions:

```
function ConstructorOne(){/*.....*/}
function ConstructorTwo(){/*.....*/}
```

Consider the following js code:

```
var myInstance = new ConstructorOne();
ConstructorOne.prototype=new ConstructorTwo();
myInstance instanceof ConstructorOne; // false - why?
myInstance instanceof ConstructorTwo; // false - why?
```

If I instantiate after assigning a prototype to the constructor, like this, all goes ok:

```
ConstructorOne.prototype = new ConstructorTwo();
var myInstance = new ConstructorOne();
myInstance instanceof ConstructorOne; // true
myInstance instanceof ConstructorTwo; // true
```

What is the reason for this anomalous behaviour in the first example?

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvtncocf/).

Answer (score 3):

Because in the first example, you assign a new prototype object to the instance's constructor. Quoting the [**docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

> ***object instanceof constructor***
>
> The `instanceof` operator tests presence of `constructor.prototype` in object's prototype chain.

In this sample:

```
var myInstance = new ConstructorOne();
ConstructorOne.prototype = new ConstructorTwo();
```

... `myInstance` prototype chain (starting with `__proto__` object) contains an *old* ("default") prototype of ConstructorOne. After it is completely rewritten with the second line of the code, `ConstructorOne.prototype` is no longer the same object that the one's in `myInstance` prototype chain - hence `false` as a result of `instanceof`.

Comment: Clear explanation, Great  Thanks!